# How to move an Azure CloudFileDirectory to a new parent CloudFileDirectory?

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I have found plenty on how to move an Azure **CloudFile**. But I need to move an entire **CloudFileDirectory**. I am really hoping I don't have to loop through all the files inside the directory and move them one at a time.

Note: we are using `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.File` and not `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.File`.
(Don't ask.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such methods in sdk / api.

Besides loop method, here are what I can think of:

1.[Mount the file storage as local drive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows), then operate it like local directory by using [Directory.Move](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.move?view=netframework-4.8) method.

2.Another way is to use [Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement/0.9.0), **version 0.9.0**(note use the latest version, which is using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.File, but it is the one you don't choose).

Then use `CopyDirectoryAsync` method to copy the content of the directory to another directory, **but after copy is completed, you also need loop to delete the source directory since it's not an empty directory**.

The sample code:

```
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials("xx", "xxx"), true);
            CloudFileClient fileClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();
            CloudFileShare fileShare = fileClient.GetShareReference("test");
            CloudFileDirectory rootDir = fileShare.GetRootDirectoryReference();

            CloudFileDirectory sourceDir = rootDir.GetDirectoryReference("t1/t2");
            CloudFileDirectory destDir = rootDir.GetDirectoryReference("t1");

            CopyDirectoryOptions options = new CopyDirectoryOptions()
            {
                Recursive = true,
            };

            TransferManager.CopyDirectoryAsync(sourceDir, destDir, false, options, null).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

          //After copy is completed, you also need loop to delete the source directory.
          //your code to delete the source directory.
```